# How to define Azure api apps to return json?

Tags: single-page-application, azure-api-apps

I created Visual studio default Azure API Apps. I call the API from SPA JavaScript but the return type is XML and I'd like it to be JSON. I tried to set XMLHttpRequest.responseType = "json" but after that the response is null.

So, how to define the Azure API App return type?

Comment: Checkout this link it talks about how to set different mediatype formatters on api apps http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters

Answer (score 0):

why are you using XMLHttpRequest? can you try using the HTTPClient

> Web API provides media-type formatters for both JSON and XML. The
>   framework inserts these formatters into the pipeline by default.
>   Clients can request either JSON or XML in the Accept header of the
>   HTTP request. JSON formatting is provided by the
>   JsonMediaTypeFormatter class. By default, JsonMediaTypeFormatter uses
>   the Json.NET library to perform serialization. Json.NET is a
>   third-party open source project.